# Should a question about a stack snippet interaction be in meta or SO?

Tags: discussion, stack-snippets

I wanted to ask a question about why some HTML/CSS/Javascript was acting differently in a stack snippet as opposed to on my local machine. However, I can find valid/invalid reasons for asking on both Meta and StackOverflow proper:

> Meta Stack Overflow is the part of the site where users discuss the workings and policies of Stack Overflow **rather than discussing programming itself**.
>
> Meta is for Stack Overflow users to communicate with each other about Stack Overflow (**asking questions about how the websites work**, or about policies and community decisions)

*Quotes from [this meta help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta).*

If I were to ask a question like this, should it be on Meta or StackOverflow? Why one or the other?

Comment: Depends. If your code is attempting to open a window, it won't work because Stack Snippets run in a sandboxed iframe. I'd first look at [the blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) introducing the feature, maybe take a gander at the Related links over to the right. Maybe do some searching on Meta. Because there have already been a lot of questions like this.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan It's not attempting to open a window, and that's not what I'm asking. I'm asking if the question should be in Meta or StackOverflow.

Comment: ... and I'm saying it depends on the question. There's no general advice. I'd suggest including a copy of the question, asking whether it is better on Meta or Stack Overflow, here on Meta, or in chat.

Answer (score 1):

The question should be on Meta.

Stack Snippets only exist on the site, so it's a question about how the site works. It'd be like asking a question about using HTML tags in question/answer fields. Yes, the question involves HTML but it's still really a question about how to use the site.

It's when it's a programming question that's unrelated to how SO works that it should be on on Main instead of Meta.